# CSS Column Count two items are higher then the other

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have a little problem.
I did 3 columns and the first one is a couple of pixels lower.
Where is the problem?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mdhiC

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way, and **more practical**, is to create three div tags with style `float: left` and `width: 33%`.

Here's a demo on how it works.

[**Live demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yfkhw)

The big image of what I did is:

**HTML**

```
<div class="colContainer">
   <div class="col">
    // content goes here
   </div>

   <div class="col">
       // content goes here
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       // content goes here
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.colContainer{
   float:left;
   width:100%;
}

.col{
   float:left;
   width:33%; /*or 33.3% if you want to be more precise*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this: 
your first h2 tag under the div is having some default margin value:

```
.not h2 {
     margin: 0;
}
```